# Django models override save and new field value from related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

I have such Django models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        verbose_name=_('Rating'),
    )

class ReportInfo(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(
        Car,
        related_name='car_info',
        verbose_name='Report',
    )
```

And I need to form rating for my car instances including info from reports, in such way:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    rating = 0
    for item in self.car_info.all():
        rating += 10
    self.rating = rating
    super(Car, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So, I need to get all reports of my car, then get some other data from the report and then save rating into the field. But, `self.car_info.all()` returns me **old data**. That means next: when I click save button in admin page of a new car, my code in save method does not have access to real reports, as they are not created yet.

Do you understand? What can I do?

Comment: you can use django signals for this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: I tried, nothing changed

Comment: There is another way. After saving your car model , you can update rating..

Answer (score 3):

Flip the order with wich `ModelAdmin` calls `save_model()` and `save_related()`. This way, from `Model.save()` you will be able to reach the updated values of the related fields, as stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858559/save-the-related-objects-before-the-actual-object-being-edited-on-django-admin/35140131#35140131).

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        rating = 0
        for item in self.car_info.all():
            rating += 10
        self.rating = rating
        super(Car, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk: 
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        else:
            pass 

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        form.save_m2m()
        for formset in formsets:
            self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
        super().save_model(request, form.instance, form, change)
```

Now, `self.car_info.all()` will return the updated data.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the order of saving in Django.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858559/save-the-related-objects-before-the-actual-object-being-edited-on-django-admin) was already asked and answered.

You can simply override the save_formset for your admin site as shown in the link.