# How to save related model instances before the model instance in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals, django-transmeta

How to save the related model instances before the instance model.

This is necessary because I want to preprocess the related model's instance field under model instance `save` method.

I am working on Django project, and I am in a situation, that I need to run some function, after all the related models of instance get saved in the database.

Let say I have a model

## models.py

```
from . import signals
class Video(models.Model):
    """Video model"""

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        )

    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(
        KeyWord,
        verbose_name=_("Keywords")
    )
```

When the new instance of video model is created.

I need to 
 1. All the related models get saved first.
    a. If the related models are empty return empty or None
 2. and then Save this video instance.

I tried to do it using `post_save` signals, but couldn't succeed as there is no guarantee that related models get saved first that the model.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete, m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Video


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Video)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Video)
def index_or_update_video(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Update or create an instance to search server."""
    # TODO: use logging system
    # Grab the id
    print("Id is", instance.id)
    # Keywords is empty as keyword instance is saved later than this instace.
    keywords = [keyword.keyword for keyword in instance.keywords.all()]
    print(keywords) # [] empty no keywords
    instance.index()


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Video)
def delete_video(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("Delete index object")
    instance.delete()
```

## Update:

Can be implemented by grabbing the `post_save` signals and wait unitls
its related models get saved in db, when the related_models get saved
start serialization process and create flat json file along with the models fields and its related instance so, the flat json file can index
into elastic search server.

And the question aries, how much time should we wait in signal handler method? and how to know all instance related fields got saved in db.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        # 1. Make sure all of its related items are saved in db 
        # 2. Now save this instance in db. 
        # 3. If the model has been saved. Serialize its value, 
        # 4. Serailize its related models fields 
        # 5. Save all the serialized data into index server 

        # The advantage of using this is the data are indexed in real 
        # time to index server. 

        # I tired to to implement this logic using signals, in case of 
        # signals, when the instance get saved, its related models are 
        # not instantly available in the databse. 

       # Other solution could be, grab the `post_save` signals, wait(delay
       # the serialization process) and start the serialization of 
       # instance model and it's related to convert the data to flat json 
       # file so, that it could index in the searching server(ES) in real 
       # time. 


       # until the instance related models get saved and start to 
       # serialize the data when its
```

Comment: Are you passing Keyword instances to the keywords field or string?

Comment: @scriptmonster keyword instance

Answer (score 3):

> By the way I am using django-admin and I am not defining the logics in
>   a view, adding the related model instance is handled by django admin

In this case, you can flip the order with which ModelAdmin calls `save_model()` and `save_related()` so from `Model.save()` you will be able to reach the updated values of the related fields, as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858559/save-the-related-objects-before-the-actual-object-being-edited-on-django-admin/35140131#35140131).

```
class Video(models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        if not self.id:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        all_updated_keywards = self.keywards.all()
        ...
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk: 
            super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        else:
            pass 

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        form.save_m2m()
        for formset in formsets:
            self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=change)
        super().save_model(request, form.instance, form, change)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override model's `save()` method and save related models (objects) before saving instance.

Comment: I know how to override save() method, but can you show me an example of overriding the related models method instance

Comment: Can you give me more code for example? What exactly you doing with related objects?

Comment: When you creating new instance (Video) you need to save it first, before you connect Keywords to this instance. After that(or if you use exiting instance) you can use instance.keywords.add(keywords_query) and it will call m2m_changed (not post_save). 
You show models, but how do you use this instances and how do you save it?

Comment: By the way I am using django-admin and I am not defining the logics in a view, adding the related model instance is handled by django admin

Comment: If you realize your admin-class overrided ModelAdmin you can override method save_related and save_model. Or did you try to change sequencing of calling base methods (save_model and save_related)?

Comment: haven't tried it, I think I need to look after that,

Comment: ModelAdmin call save_model before save_related, I think because user can try to connect related objects to instance which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it out

Comment: You should provide an example of how to implement your proposal.